# How to say, without it sounding awkward, "[something] of choice" where the [something] itself is in a form of "[thing_1] of [thing_2]"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I found myself in an email conversation where a friend jokingly said I should become a Buddhist monk in a monastery in India. I wanted to get back to him saying that Japan would probably be a more likely destination as I'm a fan of the Zen flavour of Buddhism.

So I wanted to respond that this flavour is my flavour of choice. However, this being quick email response I wanted to contain all the information in one sentence ending up with

```
Personally, my flavour of Buddhism of choice is the Zen kind.
```

However, that sounds somewhat clunky and awkward to me. Is it just my impression or is there a better way to combine the "of choice" and "flavour of Buddhism" phrases?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'My Buddhism **flavour of choice** is the Zen Kind

Or, you could say it as 'My **preferred** flavour of Buddhism is the Zen Kind'.

Comment: @ SGR Except you have three choices for the adjective form of Buddhism - Buddhist, Buddhistic, and Buddhistical.

Comment: @ SGR  And flavors don't normally come in kinds.

Comment: @PhilSweet are you taking flavour in the literal sense of being how something tastes or flavour as a synonym for type? While the word kind is redundant, it is still fine to say.

Comment: I tend to use flavors as non-categorical. I would choose between flavors and types depending on how I wanted to present the collection of things. I would only use kind to refer to types, and not discrete things. Maybe it's just me. Anyway, it was a minor quibble, which is why I used a second comment. I think the decision to not use an adjective for Buddhism is far more interesting. In a literal context, we can say "ice cream flavor", but can we say Buddhism flavor?

Answer (score 0):

"My Buddhist flavour of choice is of the Zen variety."